# Internet Explorer with Angular Cookies

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, angular-cookies

I need some help finding out why my code is running on Chrome and isn't on IE 11.

Here is my problem :

Using AngularJS and ngCookies I can set and get my cookies when I use Chrome.
When I use IE 11, the code is not working the same. For example :

```
var myObject = { "prop" : "value" }
$cookies.put("MyCookie",JSON.stringify(myObject),{})
console.log(JSON.parse($cookies.get("MyCookie"))) // Syntax Error
```

The cookie is created since I can see it in network/cookies in developer tools
But I can't read it , and I don't know why.

Is IE11 requiring the 3rd parameter of `$cookies.put()` to be filled with values ?

Comment: Which version of AngularJS are you using?

Comment: I'm using AngularJS v1.5.7

Comment: Is the cookie created at least? Can you retrieve the cookie without the library ngCookies?

Comment: I guess so. I can watch my navigator's cookies and retrieve it, using developer tools

Comment: Are you running your application on an host (means not directly from filesystem)?

Comment: I use Visual Studio (IIS) to run locally my application

Comment: Ok, have you setup a base href inside you application? Please past it.

Comment: What is a base href ? Sorry

Comment: What is your domain name? `http://localhost` ?

Comment: Omg i didn't see your comment lin sorry; yes i have http://localhost:port when i work locally, and in production i have an ip